# In which vs. what vs. where

Tags: verbs

[image]

I think the answer is either a or b, but I am leaning towards a. However, the answer key says it is d? That just totally sounds wrong to me, but I can't explain why...

Comment: (c) and (d) are certainly wrong. "Where" is possible but the relative phrase "in which" seems more appropriate, thus the relative clause is "in which it is set to enter four Asian countries", where "which" has "international expansion" as antecedent, and "it" has "Netflow" as antecedent. We understand that in its international expansion, Netflow is set to enter four Asian countries.

Comment: I'd use a colon. But this sort of question, where users are asked to decide on the 'right' answer when no unarguably idiomatic answer is given, are inappropriate on ELU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the best choice would have been:

> A Florida-based company, Netflow's growth seems to hinge on its international expansion ***as*** it is set to enter four Asian countries.

But that wasn't on offer.

*How* — and one use of *what* — can be eliminated because there is no way to parse the second clause of your sentence as an indirect question.

> The Netflow executive explained how the firm was set to enter the market in four Asian countries.
>
> The Netflow executive explained what it meant for the company to enter four Asian markets.

The other use of *what* as a relative pronoun carries the meaning “[the thing(s) which](https://www.englishgrammar.org/relative-pronoun/)” and within its clause always functions as direct object.

> What your answer key says is utter nonsense.
>
> The store didn't have what you wanted.

Again, there is no possible way to complete your sentence with "the thing(s) which" or for *what* to function as a direct object for *set*, an intransitive verb.

That leaves *in which* or *where*. Since one could construe *expansion* as a space *in which* entering four Asian markets takes place rather than the location *where* it is takes place, of the options given, *in which* seems the best.